# Exporting Cake dotnet core test output to TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity, .net-core, cakebuild

I'm looking for a way to export the test output from a .NET Core application, to TeamCity via a Cake build script.

Currently, I'm simply running:

```
DotNetCoreTest("./src/MyTestProject");
```

But I can't see anything within the documentation of [ITeamCityProvider](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.TeamCity/ITeamCityProvider/) or [DotNetCoreTest](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/8191BBC4)

The above code block works from the command line, but I can't find a way to publish the test results to the build server.

Hope someone can help

Comment: What test runner are you using? If you're using [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) it should work [out of the box](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core#testing).

Comment: The project has the Nunit runner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [NUnit test runner for .NET Core](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit), you need to explicitly pass the [`--teamcity`](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/blob/master/src/dotnet-test-nunit/CommandLineOptions.cs#L298-L299) option to have it report the test results to TeamCity (see commit [323fb47](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/commit/323fb479fe894082e5e8b49452b6b9e384a29cd2)).

In your Cake script, you can do that by using the [`ArgumentCustomization`](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/50AAB3A8) property:

```
Task("Test")
   .Does(() =>
{
    DotNetCoreTest(
        "path/to/Project.Tests",
        new DotNetCoreTestSettings
        {
            ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("--teamcity")
        });
});
```

Comment: Ah yes I see. Thanks for that!

Comment: Just an FYI this no longer works if the NUnit Test Adapter is used (the runner is deprecated).

Answer (score 5):

Found myself Googling again for this situation, and stumbled across my own unhelpful comment on the other answer...

Basically, all you need to be doing in Cake is calling `DotNetCoreTest` with standard settings (nothing specific to TeamCity), and include the following NuGet packages in your test project:

- `TeamCity.Dotnet.Integration`
- `TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter`

I also have the Cake build systems module configured in `tools\modules\packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Cake.BuildSystems.Module" version="0.3.0" />
</packages>
```

This will light up the Tests tab in TC.

Comment: Shouldn't need to add TeamCity.Dotnet.Integration, just TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2017/04/test-net-core-with-teamcity/

Comment: TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter is the only thing that works for me with .NET Core 3.1